# How can I use an EC2 ip address in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I have a Flask API that I am serving with Gunicorn on an EC2 instance, I am trying to use AWS API Gateway to connect my endpoints but I get an error when trying to use the ip of my EC2 instance for the endpoint url.

My endpoint looks like this `ec2-x-x-xxx-xx.eu-west-.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/scraper/run`

[image]

Comment: didn't you forget the protocol? `http://.....`

Comment: Oh wow im an idiot, this troubled me for way too long, I was confused because in testing with postman I had no need to use the protocol, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider 2 options:

1. If your EC2 is publicly available you should check the HTTP Proxy integration part to delegate the integration request and response configuration to your Flask API oterwise you will have to configure it on your API Gateway.

If your EC2 is publicly available you should have an inbound rule 0.0.0.0/0 on it. If not I think your should consider option 2.

2. In that case, your EC2 is not publicly available this means API Gateway will not communicate with your instance through internet but through a Private Link.

Look at this blog post to configure your VPC Endpoint and then restrict and secure your communication : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice addition to what I am planning, private endpoints look pretty intimidating from that post though!

Comment: Yes I know, but once you understand how it works, it will really secure your communication between your gateway and your HTTP endpoint on your EC2. And then you will really have an api management model with your api exposed only once on your Gateway with a caching solution etc etc

Comment: What would be the security benefits using your method as opposed to requiring an API key in the request header to use the gateway?

Comment: Only in order to reduce your footprint on internet and thus reduce your possible attack surface.